# Can´t open a socket connection from J2ME to a C# server

Tags: c#, sockets, java-me, tcp, s60-5th-edition

I´m trying to open a tcp socket from a j2me midlet on a symbian device to a windows (C#) socket server. The server is working and was tested for months.
Now when I try to open a socket from the midlet

```
clientSocketConnection = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://" + ip + ":" + port);
```

it just times out with a -34 error (Could not connect).

I know the phone has network capabilities and permissions as I can open such socket connections between 2 phones (emulated) using "ServerSocket" on one side and in the same machine the server is on.

Somehow the J2ME Socket is not compatible with the C# counterpart....

```
listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Any hint on this matter would be really appreciated.
Also, should I use another type of socket on the server side? I could not find information about the AdressFamily, SocketType nor ProtocolType for the J2ME sockets.

Adding info due to the recent comments.
It´s not a firewall problem as I have no firewall and DMZ is configured for the machine ip. 
The phone (emulated) has access to internet and when I open a socket from an emulator to another, both on the same machine, using my WAN PUBLIC ip on the "client" side to find the "server" side it works.

Comment: Its not likely "J2ME Socket is not compatible with the C# counterpart"  You must have some other problem.  Most likely a Windows Firewall error or other network security problem.

Comment: Put the `socket://ip:port` into the browser of that phone and see what happens (-34 / could not connect is my guess)

Comment: @CrazyDart
It´s not a firewall problem as I have no firewall and DMZ is configured for the machine ip. I actually can see the outgoing connection attemp of the emulator with a network monitor and the server is accepting conections from a test utilty on a pc outside the local net.
Thx for the comment anyway.

Comment: @KevinDTimm
Tried doing that (although I didn´t understand what for) and it just said "Page not found. Check web address".
Real webs are working on the phone (emulator), they allways were.
Thx for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it´s solved now.
Really weird but binding a j2me listening port (ServerPort) on "localhost" it´s not the same as binding a .net listening port on "localhost".
I mean, when I made a "server" midlet listening on localhost the clients could connect, but when I did it on the .net server they couldn´t.
The "solution" was to hardcore the computer ip instead of using "localhost". I really do not understand why, but this worked...

Comment: This is because in windows you bind to an adapter.  Localhost is a different adapter and network stack than say your "local network connection #1" with an IP.  Its like opening the door from the living room to the basement and not understanding why the pizza man cant come in the front door.